# AngularJS digest postDigestQueue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

One of our page is very heavy. To decrease our watcher count and to accelerate the angular digest cycle we are using a lot the On-Time-Binding syntax `::`. We are also using [angular-bind-notifier](https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier) to avoid unnecessary watchs over our expressions on this page.

This strategy allowed us to reduce the angular digest cycle considerably.

But this strategy has **one down side**:  It uses the **`$$postDigest`** (`postDigestQueue`) to **`unwatch`** the expression after it has been evaluated successfully.

**So what ?**

At the end of the digest, angular will run through the `postDigestQueue`. As we used a lot of On-Time-Binding expressions, our `postDigestQueue` can grow up to more than 100 000 queued tasks.

The problem is that angular uses the [following code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L851) to loop over the queue:

```
while (postDigestQueue.length) {
  try {
    postDigestQueue.shift()();
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  }
}
```

> The shift method removes the element at the zeroeth index and shifts
>   the values at consecutive indexes down, then returns the removed
>   value.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Yes, `Array.prototype.shift()` is a very expensive call when there is a lot of elements in the array.

Our digest cycle will sometimes take more than 20 seconds because of that.

When we change the previous code with the following one, it is way faster:

```
for (var i = 0; i < postDigestQueue.length; i++) {
  try {
    postDigestQueue[i]();
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  }
}
postDigestQueue.length = 0;
```

**Is there a reason why they did that ? 
Shouldn't we use that much the one time binding ?**

I could see one reason: if a task add itself a need task in the queue. Is is possible ? (`$$postDigest` is a private queue) An answer would be to use `pop`instead of `shift` if the order of execution is not important, but is it ?

***Edit:*** The order seems important because the `postDigestQueue` is used with the animations.

If anyone is interested in possible official follow-ups, [I opened an issue on the issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14534).

Comment: I added your github issue to the question. That's a very interessting question!

Comment: That's a great question and seems to be an interesting improvement request.

Comment: My simple guess is that angularJS 1.x wasn't design to handle really heavy page, standard pages are supposed to be lights. This is why all pur angularJS grids are hellish when you have a huge amount of data and so they didn't optimize so parts of their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular team merged a perf improvement that will be in the next `1.5.x` release : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cb2f8c0d75bde9ac91f4129e871ff4a8301871f3

That will speed up the digest cycles especially when you use a lot `$$postDigest` like angular-bind-notifier does.